# Django Admin Urls Not Working

Tags: python, django, admin, urlconf

Some of my django urls will not work. I can visit my index page and the django admin page just fine. I can log in and create objects no problem. For example, I can create a site, like below, but when I try to visit the collection of sites, I get hit with a 404 (even after creating one). I'm using Django allauth as well, and those pages are also having troubles with my urlconf. Can anyone spot the error?

For example, this url:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://myapp.com/admin/sites/site/

No reward found matching the query
```

And this one:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://shielded-island-1440.herokuapp.com/accounts/profile/

Using the URLconf defined in litherewards.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^ ^$ [name='index']
....
^ ^reward/$ [name='reward_list']
^ ^redeem/(?P<reward_code>)/$ [name='redeem_reward']
^ ^redeem/(?P<slug>\w+)/(?P<reward_code>\w+)/$ [name='reward_confirmation']
....
^account/
^sitemap\.xml$
^admin/
```

My urlconf is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapp.views import RewardSitemap

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
admin.autodiscover()

sitemaps = {'rewards':RewardSitemap}
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^', include('myapp.urls', namespace="fluffy")),
    url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The myapp urls included in the first urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    ....
    url(r'^reward/$', RewardsList.as_view(), name="reward_list"),
    url(r'^redeem/(?P<reward_code>)/$', RedeemReward.as_view(), name="redeem_reward"),
    url(r'^redeem/(?P<slug>\w+)/(?P<reward_code>\w+)/$', RedeemConfirmation.as_view(), name="reward_confirmation"),
)
```

And finally, my `ROOT_URLCONF` is set to `myapp.urls`. The index page works just fine.

Comment: For 2nd case uri should be `/account/profile` not `/accounts/profile` no - `'s'`, or change urls.py to have pattern `^accounts/`.

Comment: change the order by bringing the url for admin on the top first

Comment: Are you using custom templates for the admin? The error has to do with your `redeem_reward` view, which is being called somewhere. You should post the full traceback.

Answer (score -1):

From the limited knowledge that i have, i see that the URl pattern has "account/" and you are accessing "http://shielded-island-1440.herokuapp.com/accounts/profile/" which won't match any of the regex patterns in your URLConf.

Can you try modifying to url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')), ?